# JQuery Refresh Issue

Tags: jquery, html, page-refresh

So, I'm working on a jQuery script to pull value and custom url (html5) attributes from selected checkboxes and create a list of links from them. I'm still working through how to create this list, but in the meantime, I'm having an issue that I can't figure out at all. I select a checkbox, press the button, and "This works" appears in its proper place for about a half a second before the page refreshes it disappears. I've tried using an if-else statement, an , and a global variable for ifChecked. None of these have yielded the desired result and I can't figure out how to fix the problem. I just need some way to display an alert if no checkboxes are selected. Any suggestions? I've created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mo1a9hg9/

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="resources">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-url="https://option1.com" value="Option 1">Option 1</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-url="https://option2.com" value="Option 2">Option 2</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" data-url="https://option3.com" value="Option 3">Option 3</label>
    <button id="showResults">Show Resources</button>
</form>
<p id="results"></p>
```

JS:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#showResults").click(function () {
        // Check if any checkboxes are selected
        var ifChecked = $('#resources :checkbox:checked').length;

        function switchCheck(n) {
            if (n == 0) {
                caseNum = 0;
            } else {
                caseNum = 1;
            }
        }
        switchCheck(ifChecked);

        switch (caseNum) {
            // Alert if no checkboxes are selected
            case (0):
                alert("Please select an option.");
                break;

                // Store value and data attributes in an array
                // Write to p#results
            case (1):
                var linkValues = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
                    return this.value;
                }).get();
                var linkURL = $('input:checkbox:checked').data('url');
                $("p#results").append("This works");
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your [`<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)'s type is `submit` by default, meaning it will submit the form in which it resides when clicked. You see your JavaScript changes made for a second, then the form submits and the page redirects.

Change that behaviour by changing the type attribute:

```
<button type='button' id="showResults">Show Resources</button>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mo1a9hg9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `preventDefault()` method on your event, to cancel the regular behavior of your button.

```
$("document").ready(function () {
   $("#showResults").click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       // The rest of your logic
   }
}
```